# How to track if user has inputted any text on the Salesforce Chatter Email Publisher

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, service-cloud-console, lightning-events, chatter-feed

How do we know when user has made any inputs on the Email Publisher? When user made any changes to this field, and accidentally closes the tab on the Service Console, there will be no pop up message that displays - user has any unsaved messages. Other fields have this functionality already but somehow for email publisher, or post to chatter or comments - this does not trigger at all. Now I want to know when user has put any inputs to these fields and trigger some actions before user can confirm and actually closes the tab. Does someone know some hackish Javascript or something? Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rye, as far as I know, warning message will only pop up when you edit case fields and tried to close the tab without saving the case. This message does not apply to chatter posts and emails.

However, you can save your chatter posts and emails as drafts.

> Draft posts save automatically as you type a post. Once you’ve added text or a rich text item to your post, **Saving...** appears next to **Share** and then changes to **Saved**. When your draft is saved, you can access it from My Drafts. 
>   See full documentation [here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=collab_draft_posts.htm&type=5).

Same goes with the Emails, but it will not be saved to My Drafts. The text inputted in the Email Editor will instead remain in the editor even if you close the tab of the case. 
See full documentation [here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=case_interaction_enabling_email_drafts.htm&type=5).

Comment: Oh gosh you're a savior! I feel silly not able to do research on 'save as draft' functionality first. This is what really bugs me, as to why these fields can't have the same warning pop up messages like other field has. But this option also rocks. Thanks a lot Loregge!